# tensorflow official example predict my own pic

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have been following tensorflow's official tutorial [Basic classification: Classify images of clothing](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification), step by step, when I come to [Make predictions](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification#make_predictions) section, I first run

```
probability_model = tf.keras.Sequential([model, 
                                         tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])
```

and then I load my own picture, and try to predict it.

```
img = cv2.imread('./shopping.png')
img = cv2.resize(img, (28,28), cv2.INTER_AREA)
img = img/255
img = np.float32(img)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
imgs = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
p = probability_model.predict(imgs)
class_names[np.argmax(p[0])]
```

no matter what pic I use, it always outputs Bag
I don't know what I did wrong, can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to train model before predicting.

Comment: module has been trained before this step with "model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)"